# Merge two plots in one figure out of class in python

Tags: python, function, class, plot

It is my first time posting in stack overflow and I am sorry if the question seems basic.
I have defined a class in another folder and in this class the plot function is defined. Is there a way to merge the two plots as one figure out of the class definition? The example of the plot defined in the class is as below:

```
    def plot_ls(self):
        plt.figure()
        plt.semilogx(self.lk['ni_x'],self.lk['si_x'],'r')
        plt.semilogx(self.lk['ni_X'],self.lk['si_X'],'k')
        plt.grid(True)
```

Then from another script is the plot function is called two times for different data series:

```
data1.plot_ls()
data2.plot_ls()
```

There will be 2 plots in 2 different diagrams. Is there a method to combine them?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to call `plt.figure()` outside of your function

```py
def plot_ls(self):
  plt.semilogx(self.lk['ni_x'],self.lk['si_x'],'r')
  plt.semilogx(self.lk['ni_X'],self.lk['si_X'],'k')
```

And then

```py
plt.figure()
data1.plot_ls()
data2.plot_ls()
plt.grid(True)
```

I'm not super familiar with the `grid` part, but I think this should do what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you. I managed to create the plot together in one diagram